# SQL where tuple in list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help in a query, i need to select for each year the name of the courses with the logest duration.
My query looks like this

```
select * 
from courses
where (cyear,duration) IN (
                          select cyear, max(duration)
                          from courses
                          group by cyear)
```

the problem with that is it's rise this following error at : `(cyear,`

> Expression de type non booléen spécifiée dans un contexte où une condition est attendue, près de ','.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support tuples with `in`.  The closest reasonable syntax is to switch to a correlated subquery:

```
select c.* 
from courses c
where c.duration = (select max(c2.duration)
                    from courses c2
                    where c2.cyear = c.cyear
                   );
```

Comment: @El.KIbrahim if that "settles" (solves) it, don't forget to upvote the answer, and mark it as the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using windows function

```
select * 
from ( select * 
            , DENSE_RANK( ) over (partition by cyear order by duration desc) as rn
     ) tt
 where tt.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could go for an `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM courses c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM cources e
              WHERE e.cyear = c.cyear
              HAVING MAX(e.duration) = c.duration);
```